# Error in installing fuzzywuzzy in IPython Notebook

Tags: python, installation, ipython, jupyter-notebook, fuzzywuzzy

I really don't know how to install a library with code. I've tried to intall fuzzywuzzy in IPython Notebook with the module pip but I get an error message:

```
In [45]:

import pip

$ pip install fuzzywuzzy==0.3.1

  File "<ipython-input-45-579762da5e80>", line 3
    $ pip install fuzzywuzzy==0.3.1
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So, How Can I install fuzzywuzzy and other packages correctly with code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip install fuzzywuzzy==0.3.1` should  **not** be run from `Ipython`, it should be run from `bash` or your equivalent shell. It is **not** a python command

```
In [18]: pip install fuzzywuzzy==0.3.1
  File "<ipython-input-18-cf3b3a7fb3ae>", line 1
    pip install fuzzywuzzy==0.3.1
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

From bash:

```
~$ pip install fuzzywuzzy==0.3.1
Downloading/unpacking fuzzywuzzy==0.3
```